# apt-get -f install is trying to remove sudo

Tags: apt, software-installation, wine

I was trying to get a program to work, and installed a different version of wine that overwrote the version of wine I already had. (That version ended up not working) So I tried installing the default version of wine i already had, and it tells me to use sudo apt-get -f install because some wine packages are missing their dependencies, but when I run -f install it won't work because it tries to remove the package "sudo"

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:i386 or
                      wine1.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:any:i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
ryan@ryan-X551MA:~$ 

ryan@ryan-X551MA:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  attr libacl1:i386 libaio1 libattr1:i386 libav-tools libavdevice53
  libavfilter3 libavresample1 libboost-filesystem1.54.0 libboost-regex1.54.0
  libbsd0:i386 libbz2-1.0:i386 libcap2:i386 libgksu2-0 libgtkglext1
  libhdb9-heimdal libkdc2-heimdal libldb1:i386 libncursesw5:i386
  libnss-winbind libntdb1:i386 libopencv-highgui2.4 libpam-winbind
  libpopt0:i386 libpython-stdlib:i386 libpython2.7:i386
  libpython2.7-minimal:i386 libpython2.7-stdlib:i386 libreadline6:i386
  libtalloc2:i386 libtdb1:i386 libtevent0:i386 libwbclient0:i386 mkvtoolnix
  ocl-icd-libopencl1 p7zip python-dnspython recordmydesktop samba
  samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules simplescreenrecorder-lib tdb-tools
  ttf-wqy-microhei winbind wine-gecko2.21 wine1.6-amd64
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaudit1:i386 libpam-modules:i386 libpam0g:i386 sudo:i386 unrar:i386
  wine1.6:i386 wine1.6-amd64 winetricks:i386
Suggested packages:
  libpam-doc:i386 dosbox:any:i386
Recommended packages:
  winbind:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sudo
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaudit1:i386 libpam-modules:i386 libpam0g:i386 sudo:i386 unrar:i386
  wine1.6:i386 wine1.6-amd64 winetricks:i386
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 1 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 129 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y


Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 201469 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sudo (1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.2) ...
You have asked that the sudo package be removed,
but no root password has been set.
Without sudo, you may not be able to gain administrative privileges.

If you would prefer to access the root account with su(1)
or by logging in directly,
you must set a root password with "sudo passwd".

If you have arranged other means to access the root account,
and you are sure this is what you want,
you may bypass this check by setting an environment variable 
(export SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes).

Refusing to remove sudo.
dpkg: error processing package sudo (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sudo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```